# Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: python, django, view

I am creating an ecommerce site. I have a product detail page that has a button on it which points to the method "add_to_cart". Add to cart requires an item_id pk in the URL, in order to add that item to the corresponding order_item to order object.

**How can I send the item_id from the current productdetail page to the add_to_cart view within the ProductDetailView**

**Error:**

```
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['checkout/add-to-cart/(?P<item_id>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

**portal/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DetailView, ListView, RedirectView, UpdateView
from django.views import generic

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required  # This is to block pages to non users using function views
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .forms import ProductForm, ContactForm
from .models import Product, Contact
from checkout.models import OrderItem, Order
from users.models import User, Profile

# Create your views here.

class ProductDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'portal/product_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            #item_id = self.kwargs['pk']
            filtered_orders = Order.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user.user_profile, is_ordered=False)
            current_order_products = []
            if filtered_orders.exists():
                user_order = filtered_orders[0]
                user_order_items = user_order.items.all()
                current_order_products = [product.product for product in user_order_items] #not sure what this does
            context = {
                'current_order_products': current_order_products
            }

            return context
```

**portal/views.py**

```
url(r'^product/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
```

**checkout/views.py**

```
def add_to_cart(request, **kwargs):
    #get the user Profile
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)

    #filter products for id
    product = Product.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get('item_id', "")).first()

    #check if the user already owns the product
    if product in request.user.user_profile.merchandise.all():
        messages.info(request, "You already own this product")
        return redirect(reverse('product_list'))
    #create OrderItem of the selected product
    order_item, status = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(product=product)
    #create order associate with the user
    user_order, status = Order.objects.get_or_create(owner=user_profile, is_ordered=False)
    user_order.items.add(order_item)
    if status:
        #generate a reference code
        user_order.ref_code = generate_order_id()
        user_order.save()

    #show confirmataion message and redirect to same page
    messages.info(request, "item added to cart")
    #return redirect(reverse('product_list'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

**checkout/urls.py**

```
url(r'^add-to-cart/(?P<item_id>[-\w]+)/$', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
```

EDIT:

It works for my ProductListView, that is not a CBV

```
def ProductListView(request):
    model_list = Product.objects.filter(data_type="1")
    script_list = Product.objects.filter(data_type="2")
    filtered_orders = Order.objects.filter(owner=request.user.user_profile, is_ordered=False)
    current_order_products = []
    if filtered_orders.exists():
        user_order = filtered_orders[0]
        user_order_items = user_order.items.all()
        current_order_products = [product.product for product in user_order_items]

    context = {
        'model_list': model_list,
        'script_list': script_list,
        'current_order_products': current_order_products
    }

    return render(request, "portal/product_list.html", context)
```

Comment: Because you're yielding an `item_id` of "".

Comment: So how can i push the item_id of the productdetail page im on into the add_to_cart

Comment: Did you try not sending empty item_ids?

Comment: I believe so, it is pulling the ID from the model "product"to generate the product detail page, the ID is 3 in the URL. From add_to_cart: product = Product.objects.filter(id=kwargs.get('item_id', "")).first()